# Xcode 10.1 Debugger not working with introduction of frameworks

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb, xcode10.1

Recently I introduced a second app target to my Xcode project and split a great portion of my codebase into frameworks. All was working fine initially, but as I created more frameworks my debugger stopped working. My project is incredibly large with a lot of components that I’d like to import into some app targets but not others.

When the app stops at a breakpoint I get the following console output:

```
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.  
Shared Swift state for <AppName> could not be initialized.
```

Breakpoints work most of the time, but occasionally the entire debugger will crash, giving me this output:

```
Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.
```

**Platforms:** OSX 10.14.3, Xcode 10.1, iOS SDK 9.0

**Total number of targets in project:** ~250

**App Targets:** 2

**Frameworks:** 117

**Tests:** 127

**Attempted fixes:**

- Updating pods
- Removing all pods
- Removing CommonCrypto as sugggested elsewhere
- carthage update --platform-iOS --no-use-binaries
- Checking for files with targets marked as main app target and framework imported by main app target
- Restarting Xcode and the computer
- Deleting derivedData
- Clean and rebuild

Comment: Looks like a bug in LLDB, I'm also seeing this. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Qix Updated my codebase for Xcode 10.2.1 and the debugger is working again. I managed to reproduce this issue in March by creating a project with dozens of internal frameworks. Since updating Xcode this project seems to be working too

Comment: So I found out what my issue was: it was due to a stack overflow due to a recursive call never breaking the codepath. I threw my project into a docker container and ran it with gdb, which caught the stack overflow and showed me the problem.